HttpContext request and response information is not provided
program.cs file is as follows

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddPersistenceServices();
builder.Services.AddInfrastructureServices();
builder.Services.AddApplicationServices();
builder.Services.AddSignalRServices();


//builder.Services.AddStorage<LocalStorage>();
builder.Services.AddStorage<AzureStorage>();

builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy => policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "https://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials()));


builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.All;
    logging.RequestHeaders.Add("sec-ch-ua");
    logging.MediaTypeOptions.AddText("application/javascript");
    logging.RequestBodyLogLimit = 4096;
    logging.ResponseBodyLogLimit = 4096;
    logging.CombineLogs = true;
});


builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<ValidationFilter>();
})
    .AddFluentValidation(configuration => configuration.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<CreateProductValidator>())
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();



builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer("Admin", options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new()
        {
            ValidateAudience = true, 
            ValidateIssuer = true, 
            ValidateLifetime = true, 
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true, 

            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Token:Audience"],
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Token:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Token:SecurityKey"])),
            LifetimeValidator = (notBefore, expires, securityToken, validationParameters) => expires != null ? expires > DateTime.UtcNow : false,

            NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.Name
        };
    });

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.ConfigureExceptionHandler<Program>(app.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>());
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
app.UseHttpLogging();
app.UseCors();



app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var username = context.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true ? context.User.Identity.Name : null;
    LogContext.PushProperty("user_name", username);
    await next();
});


app.MapControllers();
app.MapHubs();

app.Run();

code snippet
I'm performing user authentication through JWT by creating a token and sending it to the client. The client then sends this token back to the API and successfully completes the login process. However, as shown in the screenshot, I cannot access the User via HttpContext. I'm sure the token is working correctly because when I manually change the access token from the client, it logs out the session.

why dont u call the Claims that you set when the user tries to auth? i think it's much easier way to store those datas that u need. But if u wanna use the current way, i think u need to change ur auth schema.

I tried something like this: when I request a token with Postman, I can successfully make a request to a controller with [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Admin")] authorization. But when I apply the same process through a client I created in Angular, it gives me a token but I get an unauthorized access error. Should I be looking for the error in my Angular application?
